# Minimal Number in array, C#

Tags: c#

I'm getting from the user 20 Numbers and I need to print  back the array AND ALSO lowest, minimal number and its position in the array. I am wondering if my code is correct. Can you tell any typos?
P.S., it's my first week of coding, so I am kind of a "Noob", which means that my code will be pretty bad.
Links to similar problems will be appreciated as well! :)

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Hello! Enter your very important Numbers!");
int[] Numb = new int[20];
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Numbers here!");
    Numb[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
Console.WriteLine(Numb);
Console.WriteLine(Math.Min(Numb));
```

Printscreen with my error(s):
[image]

Comment: Arrays in C# are zero-based. You are starting a 1, so Numb[0] is undefined. Why don't you just run it to see if it works?

Comment: Okay, after that i fix that typo, what else do i need to do?

Comment: You can use [`LINQ`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) for this (especially [`Min`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.min?view=net-5.0) one). `Math.Min` selects minimal from two numbers.

Comment: Your solution doesn't output the index of the minimal number. If you are a beginner a good exercise would be to find Min by yourself. Define a currentMin and a currentMinIndex with reasonable defaults, run through the array, if number at index is lower than current set the two values. I'll leave the coding to you, you're the one learning.

Comment: The code will crash if the user types “abc” instead of a number. I suggest an `int.TryParse.`

Comment: @JohnG: Yes, the whole user experience generally sucks. It would also be nice to know how many numbers you should input, and how many you already have put in.

Comment: I Have actually though about doing that but its complicated for me haha

Answer (score 1):

To find out Minimum number from an array you need to use [`.Min()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.min?view=net-5.0) function from `System.Linq`

> Returns the minimum value in a sequence of values.

```
using System.Linq;

...

Console.WriteLine(Numb.Min());  //Instead of Math.Min(Numb);
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fd9B0p)

Comment: Thanks For help, but when im trying this solution, im getting this:

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'int[]' does not contain a definition for 'Min' and no accessible extension method 'Min' accepting a first argument of type 'int[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Exam 2Nd Qes C:\Users\david\source\repos\Exam 2Nd Qes\Program.cs 17 Active

Comment: Have you added `using System.Linq;` package to your program

Comment: After that i have tried to do so, it gave me Error in every line there's "Console" in it. Explain?

Comment: I added fiddle which gives you an idea of `.Min()` function. Check it https://dotnetfiddle.net/fd9B0p

Comment: okay, it has worked! thanks!